# JQuery on dynamically generated html tables

Tags: jquery, html, django

I have multiple HTML tables generated dynamically. Each row on the tables has an Edit button.
With the following code, the click event only fires for the buttons on the first table. It doesn't work for the subsequent tables. Please help me to make it work for all the tables.

In my Django template:

```
{% for parent in parents %}
  <table class="table" id="my-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for child in parent.children %}
        <tr>
          <td>{{ child.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ child.age }}</td>
          <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn-edit" data-url="{% url "app:child-update" child.id %}">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Edit
            </button>
          </td>
    </tbody>
  </table>
{% endfor %}
```

JavaScript code:

```
$(function () {

  var loadForm = function () {
  // ....
 }
};

$("table").on("click", ".btn-edit", loadForm);
```

Comment: move **$("table").on("click", ".btn-edit", loadForm);** inside dom ready

Comment: @gaetanoM If that was needed, the click event wouldn't work at all, but OP says it works on the first table.

Comment: @CertainPerformance You are right, so the answer seems wrong. Take a look to the code in the answer. It is not so clear or better i see errors. Do you agree?

Comment: Wait, `loadForm` is not in scope when you call `$("table").on("click", ".btn-edit", loadForm);`, that should result in a `ReferenceError`. It shouldn't work at all.

Comment: @OP, can you post an example of the rendered HTML? Once you fix the scoping problem (might have been a copy-paste error) I'd *think* your current code should work

Comment: Thank you, all. Fixing the scope solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Django template:

```
{% for parent in parents %}
  <table class="table" id="my-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for child in parent.child_set.all %}
        <tr>
          <td>{{ child.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ child.age }}</td>
          <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn-edit" data-url="{% url 'app:child-update' child.id %}">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Edit
            </button>
          </td>
         </tr>
         {% empty %}
         <tr>
           <td>No Records yet.</td>
         </tr>
         {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
{% endfor %}
```

jQuery:

```
$(function () {  
    var loadForm = function () {
      // ...
    };

    $("table").on("click", ".btn-edit", loadForm);

  });
```